# Imagemagick not outputting reflection on windows

Tags: windows, command-line, imagemagick

I am trying to do the same as described here http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/advanced/#reflections

I am using imagemagick on windows and the command I am using is like this -

```
convert test3.jpg -alpha on -virtual-pixel transparent -clone 0 +distort Perspective "0,0,100,50 0,394,100,344 300,394,300,394 394,0,394,0" -clone 0  -channel A -evaluate multiply .35 +channel +distort Perspective "0,0,100,-50  0,394,100,344  300,394,300,394  394,0,394,0" -delete 0 +swap -background none  -layers merge +filter  -size "594x500^!" xc:none +swap -gravity North -geometry +0+5 -composite  reflect_distort_new.jpg
```

The actual image is

[image]

The result I am getting is like this -

[image]

I was wondering if any one can help me fixing the following issues -

1. I want to add a reflection as explained in the example, but it does not appear with my command line. I have removed parenthesis from the -clone command as it was giving error on windows.
2. How to remove the black background being added there?
3. How to apply antialising as there are edges on the resultant image.

Answer (score 0):

Ah Well, after trying 1000+ times, I got it correct -

```
convert magCover1.png -alpha on   -virtual-pixel transparent ^
  ( +clone -flip -channel A -evaluate multiply .35 +channel ) -append ^
  +distort Perspective "0,0,200,100 0,788,200,788 600,788,600,850 788,0,740,50" ^
  -gravity North  -crop "1094x1000+0-5^!" ^
  -background none -compose Over -flatten -transparent white  reflect_distort.png
```

I get the following result -

[image]